# Implementing PDF.js Viewer example

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

I am running into an issue trying to implement the PDF.js viewer demo found [here](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html), but I keep running into an issue that certain properties are not being set. Checking the console there are two errors that I get:

First error:

```
app.js:883 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'setPagesCount' of null
at Object.load (app.js:883)
at app.js:666
```

Second error:

```
app.js:870 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
at app.js:870
```

I have tried resolving this issue by diving through the code myself, and comparing it to the example with no luck. I have also looked around online trying to figure out why this may be happening and have still come up empty handed. It seems to me that `this.toolbar` is not being set with anything in the `first error`, but I cannot figure out why this may be.

Through looking around online, I believe I am setting this up properly, but am not 100% positive. Here is my setup:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var pdfDoc = '@pdf';

        // Open the default file after the document is ready. Otherwise, PDFViewerApplication probably won't exist.
        PDFViewerApplication.open(pdfDoc);
    });
</script>
```

Has anyone ever experienced this before and would be able to help? If not, does anyone know where I can start to look?

An additional note is that I have moved the files outside of their original `build` and `web` directories. I thought that I changed the configuration paths in `viewer.js` to accommodate this, but perhaps I missed one?

Comment: See example: https://jsfiddle.net/pdfjs/9engc9mw/; https://jsfiddle.net/pdfjs/wagvs9Lf/

Comment: @Juky: Thank you for commenting. Your implementation does work as a basic viewer. However, it loses a lot of functionality that the demo I posted has. I actually just resolved my issue and will post my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that my issue was do to me not adding the link resource for `locale.properties` in my `HTML`. Turns out the first error I was getting was more of a red herring, and was able to solve this issue by focusing on the second error.

I added this:

```
<link rel="resource" type="application/l10n" href="[your path to]/locale/locale.properties">
```

Where all the `HTML` for the viewer is located and it loaded right up.

Comment: Just in case a user of ´<ngx-extended-pdf-viewer>` stumbles over this bug: have a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer#troubleshooting.